# How can i convert a varchar column to decimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column that contains decimal values but the datatype of the column is varchar. How can I convert it to a decimal datatype column?

Comment: Select cast(your_column as decimal) from...

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in a query as:

```
select col::numeric
```

You can change the table structure using:

```
alter table t alter column col type numeric using x::numeric;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in a query as:

```
select cast(col as float) from tbl
```

You can change the table structure using:

```
alter table tbl alter column col float
```

You can put 'float' type or any other type of decimal